# RESTful php web service and BackboneJS

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

There's a RESTful web service built on php. Currently,  it serves a mobile application only. I need to build a web application using the same API. I think it will be a single page application build on BackboneJS. The back-end is driven by Zend Framework 2.

I have worked with BackboneJS before, but I am a complete beginner in creating SPA. The first thing that concerns me is how to sync all the models and collections with a single request to the web service when a new "page" is requested. For example, the first page in my app will be a login page. That's pretty clear that all the required data at this point will be loaded with the page. However, once the user logs in, I need to "redirect" him to a dashboard which is a completely different page with a different layout and stuff. One solution comes in my mind is to make a special request to the web service with the list of API urls which are required to bootstrap the page. The service will parse the request and internally call required controllers for each api and prepare the response. I am not sure what to do with templates though. What is the best way to pull all the required templates with a single request?

I will appreciate any help and advice on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I find using the Backbone Router to setup a page route which passes in a url splat like so:

```
routes: {
    '*page' : 'page'
}

page: function (page) {
    customEvent.trigger('router:changed:page', page);
}
```

This way you are firing an event to say the page has changed and will act as a hook for other views to render and initialise. You could then create a page module to initialise the correct view like so:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    var PageModule = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#main'), // main container

        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(customEvent, 'router:changed:page', this.render);
        },

        render: function (page) {
            this.$el.empty(); // empty the view each time

            switch(page) {
                case 'dashboard':
                    // load dashboard view
                    break;
                case 'other':
                    // load other view
                    break;
            }

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Each view then loads all the templates it might need and subviews like so.

```
define(['backbone', 'insertTemplate', 'collection'], function (Backbone, InsertTemplate, Collection) {

      var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
          // do your view magic in here but as you can see you have access to a template and collection but you could add as many items as required.
      });

      return DashboardView;
});
```

The page module becomes a sort of factory method.

I would recommend taking a look at a framework like Marionette or Layout Manager as it can help with this a lot.

This is a rough example that should hopefully get you thinking. There is a few other ways of doing it but it is a start.